# reading data from file and displaying on browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript (mostly work on backend) but now I want to create a visualization and want to use javascript for it.

I have data saved in a file in format

```
id1 uid1 rating
id1 uid2 rating2
```

Just to get started, I want to read data from this file and display it on my browser?
Do I need to start server.. or can i do it just like that.

Any suggestions/directions will be appreciated.
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn about ajax,**and deal with browser differences**. A way that would work on firefox and chrome would be :

```
  <body>
  <div id="log"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();//depends on the browser , several ways to create the object
    request.onreadystatechange = function(e){
      if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status==200){
        // do whatever you need with the data
        document.getElementById("log").innerText = request.responseText;
      }
    }
    // assuming the file is called data and is located on current-path-on-server/data
    request.open("GET","data",true);
    request.send();
  </script>  
  </body>
```

more about it :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started